# Increase the accuracy of GEKKO solver

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am working on an optimization problem and I am using APOPT to solve such a problem, but the optimizer does not return an optimal solution, especially when the number of variables is a bit high (more than 500).

Comment: If the model is non-convex, you may want to try a global solver.

Answer (score 1):

As [Erwin Kalvelagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5625534/erwin-kalvelagen) correctly observed, the problem is likely non-convex. A [multi-start method](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/GlobalOptimization) or a global optimizer may be required to find the global solution. If the solver indicates a successful solution, then the Karush Kuhn Tucker conditions are satisfied for a local optimum.

If you need a few more decimal places of accuracy, the default accuracy of `1e-6` can be adjusted for the objective and equations.

```py
m.options.RTOL=1e-8
m.options.OTOL=1e-8
```

OTOL is the relative objective function tolerance for reporting a successful solution. A lower value of OTOL, such as 1e-8, will give a more precise answer but at the expense of more iterations. The default of 1e-6 is generally sufficient for most problems. However, there are times when there are multiple objectives and higher precision is required to fully resolve minor objectives. OTOL and RTOL (tolerance on the equation residuals) should generally be adjusted together.

Comment: dear Professor @john-hedengren
is it possible to use Global Optimization with Hyperopt to find a good initial guess? when the solver is APOPT  and the variables are binary

Comment: Use binary variables instead of continuous variables. Hyperopt can select from two options (0 or 1) to give binary initial guesses. APOPT will also use continuous variables to initialize because it always attempts a relaxed solution first. Take the lowest objective of all of the local minima.